Eclipse debug not breaking SpringBoot 3 application
I am upgrading spring-boot 2 to 3 (maven). It has scheduled task.
When using Springboot2, app does not get into break point when debugging "mvn spring-boot:run" with Eclipse until I added fork=false flag:
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <fork>false</fork>
    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
</configuration>
</plugin>

If I understand correctly, this is because Mvn is running a separate process.
With this flag, breakpoints works.  Apparently this flag is gone from Sprintboot 3.
What is the proper/best way to debug springboot3 app in eclipse?
